# fixed scrollable tbody to take full table width

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

tbody adjusts to the width of the first one, not the total width placing each column under its respective one in the header. How could i fix it? I need stay the header sticky on the top and a separation of heder-body of the table of 60px and the top of the scroll starts in the top of the first row of the tbody

Please can someone help me?

```html
<div class="table-container">
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr class="header-row">
                <th onclick="sortTable(0)" style="width: 15%;">
                    <h2>
                        <span>COLUMN 1</span>
                        <span class="sort-arrow"></span>
                        <span class="sort-icon">¯</span>
                    </h2>
                </th>
                <th style="width: 18.33%;"></th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(1)" style="width: 33.33%;">
                    <h2>
                        <span>COLUMN 3</span>
                        <span class="sort-arrow"></span>
                        <span class="sort-icon">¯</span>
                    </h2>
                </th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(2)" style="width: 20%;">
                    <h2>
                        <span>COLUMN 4</span>
                        <span class="sort-arrow"></span>
                        <span class="sort-icon">¯</span>
                    </h2>
                </th>
                <th style="width: 13.33%;">
                    <h2>
                        <span>COLUMN 5</span>
                    </h2>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="body-table" id="scrollable-tbody">
            <tr class="COLUMN 1">
                <td>COLUMN 1 ROW 1</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>COLUMN 1 ROW 3</td>
                <td>COLUMN 1 ROW 4</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b342somx/

Answer (score 0):

Just remove display: block; from your .body-table class

```
.body-table {
  max-height: 300px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /*display: block;*/
}
```